# spring batch 3. File conversion

Tags: spring-batch, export-to-csv, file-conversion

> Need to read multiple txt files and generate multiple csv files,
>   I want to read multiple txt files such that i can select some columns from one txt file and some from >other.My txt file is pipe seperated.
>   i am able to read a single txt file and generate multiple csv files
>   Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- ItemReader reads a complete line one by one from input file -->
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"  scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:student.txt" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <!-- Mapper which maps each individual items in a record to properties in POJO -->
                <bean class="com.springbatch.ExamResultFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>

            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <!-- A tokenizer class to be used when items in input record are separated by specific characters -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- CSV ItemWriter which writes the data in CSV format -->
<bean id="CSVWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:output/examResultcsv1.csv"></property>
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"></property>

    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=","></property>

            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                  <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="studentName, percentage" />
                   </bean>
            </property>         
        </bean>          
    </property>             
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? Specifically: how many input files do you have, and what is their format (are the inputs pipe separated)? Also, am I correct that you need to combine fields from InputFile1 and InputFile2 to create a single OutputFile? It will be easier to help if we get more detail.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want, i have two input text files which are pipe seperated and i want to combine some fields from inputFile1 and inputFile2 to create  multiple CSV files, where different CSV files will have few fields from above text files.FieldSetMapper

Comment: I am using  FieldSetMapper to set fields to POJO.

Comment: There's no clean way to do this because you can't easily guarantee File 1 and File 2 match for each row. I'd load them into 2 tables and join the 2 tables in a select statement to create your CSVs